# SQL Query Average Time NOT Taking Weekends and Holidays into account

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to average the time it takes from creation (a.Date_Create) to completion (s.Date_Status_Finalized) of a field.

Not being able to count weekends and holidays.

The following query is working, however, takes into consideration every day of the period.

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(HH, a.Date_Create, s.Date_Status_Finalized)) 
FROM RTRC_Processo p
Left join RTRC_Solucao s on (s.Id_Processo_RTRC = p.Id )
Left Join RTRC_Abertura a on (a.Id_Processo_RTRC = p.Id) 
WHERE 1=1 
and s.Status ='F' 
and YEAR(s.Date_Status_Finalized) = 2019
and MONTH(s.Date_Status_Finalized)= 08
```

Comment: (1) Provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: sql-server-2012

Comment: Those table s conditions in the WHERE clause make that LEFT JOIN to return regular INNER JOIN result. Move them to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: If you want to exclude weekends and holidays, You need to pass a holiday table to exclude the holidays. For weekends just pass the condition that it should not match with that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For excluding the weekdays, you need to use below query where i just find the differences in days and multiplied that by 24 to get the hours -

```
SELECT AVG(
          (DATEDIFF(DD, a.Date_Create, s.Date_Status_Finalized) - 
           DATEDIFF(WK, a.Date_Create, s.Date_Status_Finalized) * 2 -  
           CASE WHEN datepart(dw, @d1) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN datepart(dw, @d2) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ) * 24 ) 
FROM RTRC_Processo p
Left join RTRC_Solucao s on (s.Id_Processo_RTRC = p.Id )
Left Join RTRC_Abertura a on (a.Id_Processo_RTRC = p.Id) 
WHERE 1=1 
and s.Status ='F' 
and YEAR(s.Date_Status_Finalized) = 2019
and MONTH(s.Date_Status_Finalized)= 08
```

Similarly, for excluding the holidays, you need to subtract the no of holidays occured in this period by using holiday table.

Comment: the return is in hours?

Comment: Don't you need it in hours?

Comment: pefect. Thank you